# Laravel & MySQL: Duplicate entry inside loop and error on mass insertion to table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-s3

I have this function to upload images to Amazon S3 and store the information about image inside my table "images".

Everything works perfectly on my localhost (uploads to amazon s3 and store the data inside table) and localhost has php 5.5.6, but on my webserver with PHP 5.5.2 I'm able to upload images to Amazon S3 but **NOT** inserting data into my table doing mass/bulk insertion:

```
/*
 * HANDLES FILE UPLOAD
 */
public function fileUpload($user_id,$car_id) {
    if (Input::hasFile('images')) {

        # Initialize array for mass inserting into table
        $insert = array();
        # General info
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
        $created_at         = new DateTime;
        $files = Input::file('images');
        $main_img = Input::all()["image-upload"][0];
        $countlimit = 0;
        try {

            foreach($files as $file) {
                if($countlimit>=25 || in_array($file->guessClientExtension(), ['jpg','jpeg','png','gif'])==false) continue; $countlimit++;

                    # Image data
                    $image_id = mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999);
                    $extension= $file->guessClientExtension();
                    $filename = $user_id.'/'.$car_id.'/'.$image_id.".".$extension;
                    $path = $file->getRealPath();
                    $is_main = ($file->getClientOriginalName() == $main_img) ? 1 : NULL;

                    # UPLOAD TO AMAZON S3
                    $s3 = AWS::get('s3');
                    $obj = array(
                        'Bucket'     => $_ENV['aws_bucket'],
                        'Key'        => 'cars/'.$filename,
                        'SourceFile' => $path,
                        'ACL'        => 'public-read',
                    );
                    $result = $s3->putObject($obj);

                    #ARRAY FOR STORING IMAGE DATA
                    $insert[] = array(
                        'car_id'            => $car_id,
                        'image_id'          => $image_id,
                        'image_extension'   => $extension,
                        'is_main'           => $is_main,
                        'url'               => $filename, # $url, FOR IMGIX JUST STORE $FILENAME
                        'created_at'        => $created_at
                    );
            }

            # Mass insertion
            DB::table('images')->insert($insert);

        } catch(Exception $e) { return false; }

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to mass insert to my database this way it doesn't store the images, curiously if I do a single query it works.

Other things I've tried are doing a query/insertion on each iteration but I get a 'Duplicate entry' error for the 'image_id'. What could it be? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually CATCH the exception that might be being thrown i.e. `PDOException` in your try/catch you may find some useful information that will allow you to identify the error all on your own.

*I am assuming you have set PDO to throw exceptions*

```
    try {

        foreach($files as $file) {
            if($countlimit>=25 || 
               in_array($file->guessClientExtension(), ['jpg','jpeg','png','gif'])==false) 
               continue; 
            $countlimit++;

            # Image data
            $image_id = mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999);
            $extension= $file->guessClientExtension();
            $filename = $user_id.'/'.$car_id.'/'.$image_id.".".$extension;
            $path = $file->getRealPath();
            $is_main = ($file->getClientOriginalName() == $main_img) ? 1 : NULL;

            # UPLOAD TO AMAZON S3
            $s3 = AWS::get('s3');
            $obj = array(
                    'Bucket'     => $_ENV['aws_bucket'],
                    'Key'        => 'cars/'.$filename,
                    'SourceFile' => $path,
                    'ACL'        => 'public-read',
            );
            $result = $s3->putObject($obj);

            #ARRAY FOR STORING IMAGE DATA
            $insert[] = array(
                    'car_id'            => $car_id,
                    'image_id'          => $image_id,
                    'image_extension'   => $extension,
                    'is_main'           => $is_main,
                    'url'               => $filename, # $url, FOR IMGIX JUST STORE $FILENAME
                    'created_at'        => $created_at
                );
        }

        # Mass insertion
        DB::table('images')->insert($insert);

    } 
    // added catch of PDOException
    catch(PDOException $e ) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) { 
        return false; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I'm getting the error I mentioned: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'images_image_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `images` (`car_id`, `created_at`, `image_extension`, `image_id`, `is_main`, `url`) values (..."

Comment: Wich doesn't make sense because image_id is a random number on each iteration :(

Comment: Pseudo randon number generators are not that good. Why not make the `image_id` an `auto increment` field then there would never be a clash. Or start the `image_id` at 1 and check the diretory contents for the largest number actually used in that directory and then add 1 to it for this file being stored

Comment: I'm doing this for my entire project without any issue, also everything works on localhost but not on my webserver, it's frustrating :/

Comment: You are lucky, or rather **unlucky** you found this issue late in the development process. However it was bound to happen at some point, lucky you found it now and not 6 months down the line.

Comment: But this shouldn't be happenning, it never happened on my localhost, EVERY single time I create a new record on different times the mt_rand() function always return 2147483647 how in the world is this possible?

Comment: I investigated more about the number I just told you "2147483647" and it was showing every time because I was generating a number of 10 digits when the limit is 9. Thank you for your help

Comment: Gotcha! I will have to remeber that.